# Dynamic allocated class object

Tags: c++, class, memory-management, dynamic

I have simple class which you can see below:

### Questions

1. Can I have in my `Playground` class constructor like this `Playground(int aRow, int aColumn);` If ***YES*** how I must allocate memory in then case for elements of row and column ? If ***NO*** why ?
2. Why I can't write `mPlayground[0][0] = 0` and what can I do to do that ? If I can of course.

#### Playboard.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef PLAYBOARD_H
#define PLAYBOARD_H

class Playground
{
public:
    Playground()
    {       
    }
};

class Playboard
{
public:
    Playboard();
    ~Playboard();

private:
    Playground** mPlayground;
    int mRows;
    int mColumns;

public:
    void Initialize(int aRow, int aColumn);
};

#endif /** PLAYBOARD_H */
```

#### Playboard.cpp

```
#include "Playboard.h"
Playboard::Playboard()
{
    mPlayground = 0;
}

void Playboard::Initialize(int aRow, int aColumn)
{
    // Set rows and columns in order to use them  in future.
    mRows = aRow;
    mColumns = aColumn;

    // Memory allocated for elements of rows.
    mPlayground = new Playground*[aRow];
    // Memory allocated for elements of each column.
    for (int i=0; i<aRow; i++)
        mPlayground[i] = new Playground[aColumn];
}

Playboard::~Playboard()
{
    // Free the allocated memory
    for (int i=0; i<mRows; i++)
        delete[] mPlayground[i];
    delete[] mPlayground;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried your code in a compiler? I can't see what is wrong with it.

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't be using `new`. If you do, you'll leak memory should one of the allocations fail. We usually use `std::vector` in C++ for arrays.

Comment: @BenRussell have you read the questions?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I think he don't

Comment: @avakar I know about `std::vector` but I do not want to use it. I want to write my class without using stl library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1a Can I have in my Playground class constructor like this Playground(int aRow, int aColumn);

Yes, trivially:

```
class Playground {
    int x, y;
    Playgrown(int aX, int xY) : x(aX), y(aY) {}
};
```

> 1b If YES how I must allocate memory in then case for elements of row and column ? If NO why ?

You don't have to allocate memory at all. `Playground` contains no pointers, and consequently requires no allocation.

> 2 Why I can't write `mPlayground[0][0] = 0` and what can I do to do that ? If I can of course.

Because you haven't overloaded the assignment operator for `Playground`. For example,

```
class Playground {
    …
    // Sample operator=. You'll need to implement its semantics
    void operator=(int) {}
};
```

---

You cannot initialize members of the array with `new`. You might be able to do this:

```
{
    mPlayground[i] = new Playground[aColumn];
    for(int x = 0; x < i; x++)
      mPlayground[i][x] = Playground(3,4);
}
```

Comment: Operator = doesn't return void.

Comment: I want to write something like this `mPlayground = new Playground(2, 4)*[aRow];`

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - Yes, `operator=` is perfectly capable of returning void. See [here](http://ideone.com/6mM6P) for an example.

Comment: @ViToBrothersApoyan - Assuming that you could write that, what do you intend it to mean?

Comment: @Rob you're right, sorry. I knew you could, but didn't think it was standard. +1

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes:

```
Playground(int aRow, int aColumn)
{
}
```

2) EDIT: Sorry I thought it was a more complicated matter. I'll leave the below answer here for future reference. To be able to write `mPlayground[0][0] = 0`, you'll need to overload

```
Playground& Playground::operator = ( int x );
```

#### Old answer:

To be able to access `Playground` objects from the `Playboard` class, you can overload the `()` operator and call:

```
Playground Playboard::operator()(int r, int c)
{
    return mPlayground[r][c];
}

//...
Playboard p;
p(x,y);
```

or the `[]` operator:

```
Playground* Playboard::operator[] (int r)
{
    return mPlayground[r];
}

 //...
 Playboard p;
 p[x][y];
```

Comment: The OP's question is unclear, but his `Playground` doesn't have a member `mPlayground`. It appears that `Playboard` contains the `Playground` array, not that `Playground` contains an additional `Playground` array.

Comment: But can I call from `Playboard::Initialize` Playground constructor with arguments ?

Comment: @ViToBrothersApoyan I edited the answer for the second question.

Comment: @ViToBrothersApoyan ok I thought you were asking something different. Corrected now.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore thanks for second answer but I still can't understand firs as I have no `mPlayground` in my Playground class

Comment: @ViToBrothersApoyan I mixed up the names. `Playground` and `Playboard`. At this hour, I just see `Plablabla` :). Why do you need parameters for the constructor of `Playground` thought?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore as I want to save same information in `Playground` class

Comment: @ViToBrothersApoyan ok. Then that's the way to do it.

Comment: I have `Playboard` which contains `Playgrounds` every `Playground` must have its own class members.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore "Then that's the way to do it." and how ?

Comment: @ViToBrothersApoyan `Playground(int aRow, int aColumn)` like this.